# What does "Expanding...." mean in AWS CodeBuild logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

In the CodeBuild log "artifacts" phase I see "Expanding...." message in the logs. It shows up not only for directories but also for files. But for binary files it says "Skipping invalid file path...".

I searched everywhere but did not find any explanations.